# Facebook login in my iPhone application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, facebook-graph-api, mobile-safari, facebook-login

I have added the Facebook API to share my application information. I have tested the login, but when I tap on the *Login* button in my application, Safari opens with the login page. I would handle this login in my application (for example in my web view). How can I do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [iOS Facebook library login](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/7086149/ios-facebook-library-login)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want it to open the login in-app, head to the `Facebook.m` file and look for the method `-(void)authorize:(NSArray *)permissions`

and change the line

```
[self authorizeWithFBAppAuth:YES safariAuth:YES];
```

to

```
[self authorizeWithFBAppAuth:NO safariAuth:NO];
```